# Racket REPL over TCP

Tags: scheme, eval, racket, read-eval-print-loop

I've built a rather complex application with Racket (formerly PLT Scheme) and would like to add a REPL for debugging purposes. I've tried to make it accessible over a TCP stream:

```
(define repl-server
  (thread (lambda ()
          (let ((listener (tcp-listen 8082 5 #t)))
            (do () (#f)
              (let-values (((in out) (tcp-accept listener)))
                (thread (lambda ()
                          (let ((port-string (get-port-string in)))
                             (Try "debug-repl" #f
                               (begin
                                 (file-stream-buffer-mode out 'line)
                                 (display-and-log "Password: " out)
                                 (flush-output out)
                                 (when (string=? (read-line in) "whatever")
                                   (log "Connect to REPL: " port-string))
                                   (current-input-port in)
                                   (current-output-port out)
                                   (current-error-port out)
                                   (read-eval-print-loop))
                                 (close-input-port in)
                                 (close-output-port out))))))))))))
```

`(Try name result-if-exception form)` is a macro providing basic exception handling, (log ...) and (display-and-log ...) do what they sound like.

Now if I access the REPL, I can't even evaluate constants, as I keep getting the error `compile: unbound identifier (and no #%app syntax transformer is bound) at: #%top-interaction`. How can I make this REPL work? And how can I access values `define`d before starting the REPL server?

Comment: Great question! You should really, really, ask this question on the racket mailing list, http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/ . I can predict the following: 1) there is a way to do it. 2) It may be quite painful. 3) You might want to look at sandboxes.

Comment: Note to self: Next time, use `addlog` or the like as the name of that function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `read-eval-print-loop`, which is essentially the same as using `eval`, and therefore suffers from the same kind of problems.  See the [relevant Guide section](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html) for a detailed explanation.  It's best to read that completely, but the answers that you're looking for are either what the "Namespaces" section describes, or the "Namespaces and Modules" section -- the first is if you want a toplevel kind of a namespace, and the second is if you want a namespace that corresponds to the actual file that the code appears in.  (The first is usually better -- for example, if you use the second then `repl-server` is itself available for the REPL user, making it a questionable feature...)

Here's how it would look like:

```
...
(thread (lambda ()
          (parameterize ([current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
            ...same code...)))
...
```

and for the second one, define an anchor and use `namespace-anchor->namespace` as the last example on that page shows.

[BTW, see also the [`run-server`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/mzlib/mzlib_thread.html#%28def._%28%28lib._mzlib/thread..rkt%29._run-server%29%29) thing, it's a little old, but can still be useful.]

Comment: Works flawlessly! I actually used the second case as this is supposed to be a debug hack not accessible by normal users. Full access to a running program! I'm literally jumping with joy right now :)

Comment: For the record, John's comment is also very relevant -- the `racket/sandbox` library is also relevant for making robust repls.  (But obviously it's less in the direction that you want to go, judging by the above comment.)